# Why are my CASTS seemingly ignored in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, truncation

I use a **Data Flow Task** in SSIS to get data from one server (SQL Server 2005) to another (SQL Server 2008 R2). In the **OLE DB Source** connection I use an SQL command to get the data. In this command, I am already casting content as a certain data type:

```
SELECT
CAST(column1 AS VARCHAR(10)) AS NameColumn1
,CAST(column2 AS INT) AS NameColumn2
,CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column3, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), ''), ';', '-') AS VARCHAR(100)) AS NameColumn3
,CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column4, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), ''), ';', '-') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS NameColumn4
...
FROM (etc.)
```

(Note that the casts are casting to the original data type of the column values in the source database. So the data type of column1 is originally `VARCHAR(10)`, that of column4 is originally `VARCHAR(255)`, etcetera.)

These casts are used because further on in the package I got the following warning for `column3` and `column4`:

> Validation warning. [...] Truncation may occur due to inserting data
>   from data flow column "column4" with a length of 8000 to database
>   column "column4" with a length of 255.

It seems as if the casts do not work though, because the truncation warnings for column3 and column4 keep coming. (I have already set the truncation warning in the **OLE DB Source** to *Ignore failure*, but that does not seem make a difference.)

I can't find anything on this online and will for the time being 'solve' this by importing the columns as `VARCHAR(8000)`. But I'd love to know what the cause of this behaviour in SSIS is. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: r u using any `derived column` thereby converting its length to 8000 because the error clearly states that the `column4` is having a length of `8000` in the `source table` and you are trying to map to a column in `destination` having `255` length ?

Comment: No, because `column4` is data type `VARCHAR(255)` in the source table. This length of 8000 seems to come out of thin air...

Comment: `Right click` on OLEDB source and manually change the length for the column 4 and just in case check the property `ValidateExternalMetadata` in `Destination` or `Source` .It should be `true`

Comment: If you change the CAST to a CAST to, say, Varchar(10). does that change the error message? (In that case, the truncation warning is caused by the cast and the 40000 is just SSIS max. size that an intermediate column gets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the Advabnced Properties of the source component and verify the size of the 3rd and 4th columns (within Input and Output Properties).  If they have already been calculated as varchar(8000) then you will have to change them manually.

Alternatively, delete the component and add a new one with your Select / Cast in place from the beginning - this should correctly assign the right field length.

Comment: As an alternative to deleting the component, just change the query to something like `SELECT 1 as tmp`. After clicking OK, the output buffer's metadata will get reset to a single column with data type int. Then paste your query back in. The underlying problem being that the source components don't always care if the source column is smaller than originally declared. Logic seems to be "String 255 fits in string 8000 so no need to refresh metadata."

Comment: @billinkc: your suggestion did the trick! Apparently the issue was due to the metadata not being refreshed... Thanks both for your suggestions! Learned something new today :-)